# Why does $A_1(T_p \mathbb{R}^n)={T_p}^{*}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, multilinear-algebra

Hi i am reading about manifolds and there it is mentioned that $A_1(T_p \mathbb{R}^n)={T_p}^{*}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $A_k(V)$ is the space of alternating k-linear functions. Why does the above equality holds? Does the equality hold in general that is $A_k(T_p \mathbb{R}^n)={T_p}^{*}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I know that on the rhs we have the cotangent space at $p$. Is this by definition or is there a proof for this? Is this because **the basis for both lhs and rhs is same**?

Comment: This has nothing to do with manifolds in particular; you can answer the following for any vector space $V$: what is an alternating $1$-form on $V$?

Comment: Are you asking whether the equality $A_k(T_p\Bbb R^n)=T_p^*(\Bbb R^n)$ holds for every $k\in\Bbb N$. In particular, are you asking whether all spaces $A_k(T_p\Bbb R^n)$ are equal to each other?

Comment: @Thorgott Yeah i have added one more hint at the end, you can check that .

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos obviously they won't be all same otherwise what is the point. Ok so it is not true in general. Now is it equal for k=1 for the reason that i have mentioned at the end of the question, can you check?

Comment: I don't follow your "hint". Can you answer my question or not?

Comment: No, it's because *by definition* $A_1(V)=V^*$ for any vector space $V$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yeah i got it, posted it as an answer myself.Thanks

Comment: No, an alternating 1-form is *an element* of the space of all alternating 1-linear functions. Your wording is sloppy. Nor is the cotangent space the space of all functions from $V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. You need to be precise.

Comment: @Thorgott good catch. I edited my answer to say: An alternating 1-form on V will be the space of all alternating 1-linear functions. That is functions from →ℝ and that we know equals to the dual space $V^*$. I wrote it in hurry(& excitement) , thanks for catching that typo.

Comment: Your edit does not address my complaints.

Comment: @Thorgott Yeah $A_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the space of all alternating 1-linear functions.And so a 1-form will be an element of $A_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.Again my fault in the wording. Elements of $A_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are functions from $V\to \mathbb{R}$. And therefore this space is nothing but the dual space of V.

Comment: Elements of $A_1(V)$ are *not* just functions from $V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Neither is that the dual space. The functions in these spaces have certain additional properties, which you are neglecting.

Comment: @Thorgott Dual space of a vector space $V$ is by definition the space of all linear functionals from $V\to \mathbb{R}$ . It is denoted by $Hom(V,\mathbb{R})$. What additional properties am i neglecting about these spaces? Are you saying that the lhs and the rhs of the equation $A_1(T_p \mathbb{R}^n)={T_p}^{*}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ aren't equal ?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the adjective "linear" is crucial here and you didn't mention it before. The dual space are the *linear* maps $V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. The space $A_1(V)$ is the space of *alternating 1-linear* maps $V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Now you have to note that "linear" and "alternating 1-linear" are equivalent properties for these maps.

Comment: @Thorgott Well i mentioned it when writing the definition of $A_1\mathbb{R}^n$ as the space of all alternating 1-linear functions. And  so i already established that the functions i am talking about are linear and didn't feel the need to mention it again in the next sentence.

Answer (score 1):

$A_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the space of all alternating 1-linear functions. That is functions from $V\to \mathbb{R}$ and that we know equals to the dual space $V^*$. Hence proved